# Eclipse Java web app servlets not working when deployed to AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, eclipse, tomcat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am hosting my first EE Java web app on AWS using Elastic Beanstalk and the project .WAR file. The environment is Tomcat 8.5 with Coretto 11 (64 bit amazon linux 2) and the project is optimized for Tomcat 8.5. The project works fine in eclipse but not when deployed to the beanstalk environment.

Here is my project directory: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NG1C.png

ajax request in index.jsp:

```
          $(document).ready(function () {
           
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : 'ExampleServlet',
                data : {},
                success : function(returnValue) {
                    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'Success';
                },
                error : function(req, err) {document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'error';}
            });
            
        });
```

Example servlet:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

@WebServlet("/ExampleServlet")   
public class ExampleServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   
    public ExampleServlet() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

Its a simple POST request but it keeps displaying an error once deployed. I am not using Maven, SpringBoot, etc.

Edit:

Edit:
I finally found the correct logs after ssh into instance: /var/log/tomcat/localhost.[date].log

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Zn4t.jpg

08-Oct-2022 14:11:48.182 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Allocate exception for servlet [ExampleServlet]
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: ExampleServlet has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0 (unable to load class [ExampleServlet])

I'm assuming there is a version mismatch of the jdk on my system...
I am using JDK 8 but Tomcat 8.5 uses JDK 7? Will try different version and update..

Comment: *What error is it displaying?"*

Comment: Just the response from ajax that the request failed, which is literally 'error.'

Comment: And in the server log?

Comment: Sry, found the logs just now. Apparently jdk mismatch? I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse version mismatch. Swapped Eclipse's default Java version (16) for version 11. Everything compiles.